# Are domain objects ment to be injected?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm already using **CDI** `@Inject` to get some stateless services in some of my classes.

I wonder if it would also make sense to inject domain objects, like the following example:

```
class UserSettings;

class User {
    //@Inject
    private UserSetttings settings = new UserSettings();
}
```

A user should always have some default settings attached, that can be altered later. Would you use CDI here, or just stick with manual creation of a new object?

Or more general speaking: where makes it in general sense to use CDI? And where not?

---

Update Producer:

```
class Preferences {
    @Produces @DefaultSettings
    public UserSettings getDefaultSettings() {
        UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();
        //configure default
        return settings;
    }
}


class User {
    @Inject @DefaultSettings
    private UserSettings settings;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain objects can be injected.  You probably don't want to inject the default domain object, instead you want to provide a producer for it.  This producer would essentially create the domain object based on some setup.  You could have a "manager" type class that loads the object with the necessary properties based on something, like the current logged in user.  Right now I do something similar, taking the principal and using that to look up the information for the logged in user, creating something like `UserSettings`.  You just need to ensure that your `UserSettings` is not injectable, using a veto extension or not even installing it.

The alternative (which I don't particularly like, but could work) is for your domain object to inject references to persistence domains to look up the data.  Conceptually, it looks a little cleaner.  The setup code would go in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: So, as I'm new to Producers: I updated my initial post - is this what you would suggest in this case? Or if not, could you give an example?

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it.  `@DefaultSettings` is for not logged in?  Would there be another for cases where the user has custom settings?

Answer (score 0):

> A user should always have some default settings attached, that can be
>   altered later. Would you use CDI here, or just stick with manual
>   creation of a new object?

If your application is `CDI` enabled then you should use `CDI`, rather than manual creation of new object.

> where makes it in general sense to use CDI? And where not?

`CDI` has many broader uses, allowing developers a great deal of flexibility to integrate various kinds of components in a loosely coupled but typesafe way. So, CDI should use on all `Java EE 6` and `EE 7` applications. If `CDI` is not supported by your application, then you should not used it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more aspect: good code can be tested. And using dependency injection to support "Inversion of Control" is always a good idea. Think about how you would test your code, if the Settings are created internally via

`private final UserSettings s = new UserSettings();` ...

It's much easier to make it injectable and then use an injection framework in test scope (tip: use needle (https://github.com/akquinet/needle)).